# Get depth of call stack in gcc

Tags: c, gcc

I want to write a debug printing function that prints **LINE**, **FILE**, **func** and some other stuff. The twist is that I'd like to automatically indent the printouts according to their depth in the call stack, so something like

```
main.c:55:main()
   functions.c:33:function1()
   functions.c:133:function2()
      functions.c:33:function1()
      functions.c:33:function1()
```

if function1 returns immediately, and function2 calls function1 twice.

I guess this could be done by using a global variable which is manually incremented each time a function is called and decremented whenever it is returned, but this would require quite the code base rehaul. I was wondering if there was an easier way to do it?

I don't mind if the solution is non-standard C, so long as it is standard GNU.

Comment: [Tip](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/BTDT): Instill some control to limit the height up the stack that code searches as the stack could be _very_ deep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can probably do this with the code profiling options in Gcc.
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.2/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html

> **-finstrument-functions**
>   Generate instrumentation calls for entry and exit to functions. Just after function entry and just before function
>   exit, the following profiling functions will be called with the
>   address of the current function and its call site. (On some platforms,
>   __builtin_return_address does not work beyond the current function, so the call site information may not be available to the profiling
>   functions otherwise.)

```
void __cyg_profile_func_enter (void *this_fn,
                               void *call_site);
void __cyg_profile_func_exit  (void *this_fn,
                               void *call_site);
```

Comment: That's great! If I understand it correctly, GCC only provides the prototypes and it's up to the user to implement them in whatever way he/she chooses?